# TikZ "callout" positioning problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, texlive

I have just recently upgraded my `TeXLive` from version *2010*  to *2011* (OS versions  Ubuntu 10.10/Maverick 32-bit and Windows 7/64 bit).

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (Web2C 2011)
(format=pdflatex 2011.8.10) 15 AUG 2011 09:34
```

To test the new version I thought it would be a good idea to try to compile some of my older documents. It all went flawlessly until I got to a paper that had some TikZ graphics, which produced errors. After some investigation I had found that the problem was caused by some positioning elements of TikZ. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, note/.style={rectangle callout, fill=#1}]
\draw [help lines] grid(3,2);
\node [note=red!50, callout relative pointer={(0,2)}] at (0,0) {Good};
\node [note=blue!50, callout relative pointer={(0,2)}] at (2,0) {Good};
%\node [note=blue!50, callout absolute pointer={(0,2)}] at (2,0) {Error};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The above code is a slightly modified version of the sample found in the TikZ & PGF Manual Version 2.10, page 454 (2nd sample). *The error is caused by the commented line.* Whenever absolute positioning is used, an error is generated like the one below:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgf@sh@bg@rectangle callout ...f@sh@np@\pgf@test 
                                              \noexpand \endcsname }\ede...
l.24 ...lute pointer={(0,1)}] at (1,0) {Absolute};
```

I would appreciate any pointers. Cheers.

Comment: There is now a fuller answer to this question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31921/86

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** See Daniel's answer at [callout and beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31921/86) for a fuller patch.

---

This appears to be a bug in PGF.  Looking at the relevant line in `pgflibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex`, I see the following code:

```
%
% \pgf@test = the shape name (from \pgfmultipartnode)
%
\ifx\pgf@test\pgfutil@empty%
\else%
    %
    % Now hack an extra saved anchor \calloutpointeranchor,
    % with the new anchor for the callout pointer.
    %
    \edef\pgf@sh@@temp{\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\noexpand\csname pgf@sh@np@\pgf@test\noexpand\endcsname}%
    \edef\pgf@sh@@@temp{%
        \noexpand\def\noexpand\calloutpointeranchor{%
            \noexpand\pgf@x\the\pgf@x%
            \noexpand\pgf@y\the\pgf@y%
        }%
    }%
    \expandafter\pgf@sh@@temp\expandafter{\pgf@sh@@@temp}%
\fi%
```

But when I looked at the definition of `\pgfmultipartnode` I couldn't find a place where `\pgf@test` is assigned to the shape name.  Instead, I found `\def\shape@name{#1}% CJ`.  And when I replaced `\pgf@test` by `\shape@name` in `pgflibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex` then I get what appears to be the right behaviour.  (This might not be the only fix needed: `\pgf@test` is used a couple more times in that library; the others aren't documented and aren't needed to fix **this** code.)

Long-term fix: report this on the PGF bug tracker.

Short-term fix: **copy** the file `pgflibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex` somewhere where it will be read first (personal `texmf` directory, for example) and modify it in line with the above (ie replace `\pgf@test` by `\shape@name`).

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. It solves the problem temporarily. I'll try to report this to the PGF maintainers.

Comment: @Heisenb0rg  The code compiles fine with pgf 2.1 CVS !

Comment: @Altermundus: Thanks for the info. My version is 2.10, not from CVS though.

Answer (score 3):

A permanent solution, as pointed out in the comments, is to upgrade TikZ to version 3.0, either from their [website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) or using your tex distribution's packet management tool.

If you can or do not wish to go that route, the simplest solution I found was this [non-accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62553/12467) to a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31921/86) (referenced in the [answer above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25738/12467)). 
The trick is to also include the `decorations.text` TikZ library, like so:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! After having spent a few time here, you will gain the sufficient reputation to vote up the questions you believe better.

Comment: This issue is resolved on TikZ version 3.00. So it doesn't need any workarounds.