# callout and beamer

Tags: beamer, diagrams

I am trying the callout code that Andrew has provided at [How to open a temporary comics-like balloon in a beamer slide?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5423/how-to-open-a-temporary-comics-like-balloon-in-a-beamer-slide/31912#31912), but I am getting an error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \pgf@sh@bg@ellipse callout ...pgf@sh@np@\pgf@test \noexpand \endcsname }\ede... l.20 \end{frame}
```

I am using TexLive-2011 on Mac OS X Lion (10.7.2).

Comment: I have the same problem. Also TeXlive 2011, but with WinXP.

Comment: Hmm, same issue here. Problem seems to be with the callout absolute pointer. Not really sure what is going on there. On TeTeX on Linux, yeah, I know, old... It's Tikz 2.10 though.

Comment: yes, I get the same problem, but we ignore the error, we can get the slides.

Comment: yes, but the positioning is off, isnt it? Since the absoule pointer doesn't work.

Comment: no, if you run it two times, you can get the right position.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TikZ "callout" positioning problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25736/tikz-callout-positioning-problem)

Comment: As Pig Cry notes below, this has been asked before, though Daniel's is a better answer than mine on the previous version.  Nonetheless, these ought to be linked.  That also explains why I didn't spot this in my answer on the *comics balloon* question - I have a fixed copy of the relevant file in my TeX-SX answers directory and didn't notice it was being loaded instead of the original.  My apologies for the confusion!

Answer (score 13):

This is a known bug with PGF/TikZ 2.1 (see http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/b41b47158ac5d221/b7428bd8ca1084ae?pli=1)

Save the following patch as `pgflibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex.diff` and apply it to the file `pgflibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex` (you might want to create a backup first), e.g. by

`patch -i pgflibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex.diff ${TEXMF}/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex`

(where `${TEXMF}` is the path to your local `TEXMF` directory)

```
@@ -247,9 +247,9 @@
            \pgf@lib@callouts@shortenpointer%
            \pgf@lib@ellipsecallout@getpoints%  
            \calloutpointeranchor%  
-           \ifx\pgf@test\pgfutil@empty%
+           \ifx\pgf@node@name\pgfutil@empty%
            \else%
-               \edef\pgf@sh@@temp{\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\noexpand\csname pgf@sh@np@\pgf@test\noexpand\endcsname}%
+               \edef\pgf@sh@@temp{\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\noexpand\csname pgf@sh@np@\pgf@node@name\noexpand\endcsname}%
                \edef\pgf@sh@@@temp{%
                    \noexpand\def\noexpand\calloutpointeranchor{%
                        \noexpand\pgf@x\the\pgf@x%
@@ -568,15 +568,15 @@
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pointerwidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/callout pointer width}}%
            \pgf@lib@rectanglecallout@pointer%
            %
-           % \pgf@test = the shape name (from \pgfmultipartnode)
+           % \pgf@node@name = the shape name (from \pgfmultipartnode)
            %
-           \ifx\pgf@test\pgfutil@empty%
+           \ifx\pgf@node@name\pgfutil@empty%
            \else%
                %
                % Now hack an extra saved anchor \calloutpointeranchor,
                % with the new anchor for the callout pointer.
                %
-               \edef\pgf@sh@@temp{\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\noexpand\csname pgf@sh@np@\pgf@test\noexpand\endcsname}%
+               \edef\pgf@sh@@temp{\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\noexpand\csname pgf@sh@np@\pgf@node@name\noexpand\endcsname}%
                \edef\pgf@sh@@@temp{%
                    \noexpand\def\noexpand\calloutpointeranchor{%
                        \noexpand\pgf@x\the\pgf@x%
@@ -862,9 +862,9 @@
            \pgfextract@process\calloutpointer{%
                \pgfpointanchor{pgf@lib@callout@pointer}{center}%
            }%
-           \ifx\pgf@test\pgfutil@empty%
+           \ifx\pgf@node@name\pgfutil@empty%
            \else%
-               \edef\pgf@sh@@temp{\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\noexpand\csname pgf@sh@np@\pgf@test\noexpand\endcsname}%
+               \edef\pgf@sh@@temp{\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\noexpand\csname pgf@sh@np@\pgf@node@name\noexpand\endcsname}%
                \edef\pgf@sh@@@temp{%
                    \noexpand\def\noexpand\calloutpointeranchor{%
                        \noexpand\pgf@x\the\pgf@x%
```

Comment: The suggested patch fails with the following error:
(Patch is indented 4 spaces.)
patching file pgflibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex
Hunk #1 FAILED at 247.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 568.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 862.
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file pgflibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex.rej

Any idea why?

Comment: +1 Applying the patch by manually modifying the file worked. Thanx for the patch.

Comment: @01es: The indentation of the patch was indeed the culprit: The the `@@` lines **must** start with column 1. All others: I have edited the patch so that a simple Copy&Paste should now work.

Answer (score 9):

http://old.nabble.com/callout-absolute-pointer---desired-effect-but-compile-error-td30937456.html gives a much less intrusive solution:
Make sure you have the following in the preamble:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
```

The second library is the non-intuitive part; it defines the missing `\pgf@test`.

Indeed worked for me with pgf 2.10-1 (ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: in addition to user7725's post, in my case the decoration.text solution worked, while the patching produced wrong output (callout pointing to (0,0) in place of the specified point)

Comment: This works for me.

Answer (score 3):

There is a similar question [TikZ “callout” positioning problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25736/tikz-callout-positioning-problem). I find other solution from internet, we can replace all `\pgf@test` by `\pgf@node@name` in `pgflibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex`.

Comment: Well spotted!  I've linked the questions together, particularly as Daniel's answer above is the fuller answer.