# How can oversets and undersets be allowed to appear over neighboring text?

Tags: spacing, context

I am using the `\overset` and `\underset` commands in ConTeXt, to place text over other text within a paragraph, e.g.:

```
(animal)                (animal)   (animal)
 Bears   like to   eat    fish  and snakes.
                (action)
```

The `\overset` command successfully places text above, but it also creates spaces in the main text, as shown above. I would prefer it the main text has normal spacing when possible, e.g.:

```
(animal)         (animal)   (animal)
 Bears like to eat fish and rabbits.
            (action)
```

Only in situations where two `\oversets` or `\undersets` appears next to each other and require more space than the regular text should extra spacing be added, e.g.:

```
(animal) (animal)   (animal)
 Bears,    fish, and frogs  eat,    play, and swim in the river.
                         (action) (action)  (action)
```

- How can I condense the spacing around text when `\oversets` and `\undersets` are used, to the extent that is possible?

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38805/simple-speech-bubbles-arrows-or-balloon-like-shapes-in-beamer/) might be interesting for you.

Comment: You can play with `\llap`, though it's not a solution, just a workaround.

Comment: @Marco: why not define `\clap`?  I wrote a short answer with this idea.

Comment: You can also look at the `ruby` module by Wolfgang Schuster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a plain TeX solution (which, as Aditya mentioned, is already implemented in ConTeXt, even in a better, math-mode-compliant way)::

```
\def\clap#1{\hbox to 0pt{\hss #1\hss}}
```

Now `\clap{whatever}` sets *whatever* as if it had zero width, centered horizontally around the point it was encountered by TeX.

(Obviously, this macro follows the idea of `\llap` and `\rlap`.)

Of course this won't help when oversets etc. *overlap*.

**Edit:** as Marco pointed out in the comment, this might be better idea:

```
\def\clap#1{\hbox to 0pt{\hss\strut #1\hss}}
```

The `\strut` macro makes the `\clap` box as high (and deep) as the "highest/deepest" character in the font (at least in theory - but unless the settings are very weird, this should work).

Comment: IMO it makes sense to include a `\strut`, otherwise the overtext almost always appears too close to the main text.

Comment: @Marco: good point, I've included it in my answer.

Comment: ConTeXt already has a `\clap` command (that works correctly both in text and math mode).

Comment: @Aditya: oops, I didn't know that.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use a zero-with box \makebox[0pt]{} around the text you want either under or over.  e.g.,

```
\overset{\makebox[0pt]{(\scriptsize animal)}}{Bears}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The question is about ConTeXt, which hasn't `\makebox`.

Comment: useful anyway... I'm using LaTeX  and that's what I was looking for :)