# Resemble popular messenger with LaTeX macros

Tags: tikz-pgf

I once saw a latex template, which you could use to create a Chat-Like document which has an appearance similar to current mobile chat applications (i.e. iMessage or Whatsapp).

I am of course looking for a static document compiled by `latex`or `pdflatex` and not a dynamic chat program.

I remember that I saw something similar done in LaTeX already, but I was not able to find it again.

I can imagine, that this has been done with tikz before.

Example images:
[image: example whatsapp screenshot]

Comment: There seem to be at least [Quotes with speech balloons](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62086/35864) and [Simple speech bubbles, arrows or balloon like shapes in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38805/35864).

Comment: I also saw nearly very similar, and  I am almost sure that was on TeX.SX, but I am unable to find the duplicate.

Comment: Search for Gonzalo's answer (I bet he is that wizard who gives such beautiful things).

Comment: I found it http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239511/11604

Comment: This is it, I am glad, that you found it. Shall I close this question again?

Comment: @Fran I knew there *had* to be something more similar to the three questions I found. Thank you very much for taking the time to find it.

Comment: @Lukas There are not a duplicate question. Only an useful answer to another question that, moreover, was hard to find searching by  key words as Messenger, Whatsapp, etc. Therefore, IMHO this question  should be left open, but answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A good starting point is the `kik-android` document class, as well as  minimal working example of [Brian Jacobs's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239511/11604) in [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends)

The above text links are enough because are from [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), but just to compare with the image in the question, this is the result:

> [image: kik-android-class]