# Left and right colour box equation

Tags: equations, colorbox

I'm looking for solution to get colour boxes for equations below (with optional box in one of them) - one for the right and one for the left - as on the picture below.
Is it possible to get dialog boxes (with this little corner)?
[image]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270298/134144 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239511/134144