# How do I copy WhatsApp chats and retain linebreaks

Tags: line-breaking, copy-paste

I am looking to copy many whatsapp chats into a document and retain the linebreaks. If I just copy them in, then there are no linebreaks. How do I do this? Thanks

Verbatim (alone) doesn't work because it means text flows off the page

Just using \obeylines worked perfectly

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I think this isn't a LaTeX related question or could you explain the problem with latex?

Comment: @Bobyandbob I suspect the user wants just to keep line breaks as `\obeylines` or similar would do, but this question is rather unclear.

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266713/resemble-popular-messenger-with-latex-macros

Comment: Can you add some examples of what your input text looks like? I mean the text you copied into your .tex document and are trying to typeset.

Answer (score 3):

Put it into a verbatim environment. `\begin{verbatim} whatsapptext \end{verbatim}`.

---

### EDIT:

So you don't want linebreak, except in all cases where lines that are longer than let's say 72 letters? Please provide an example as »MWE«. Probably the easiest way might be to use your editor's search and replace function:

Swap each end-of-line sign with a double backslass `\\`. Then try instead of the verbatim environment the verse environment. However, it would be much easier if we had an MWE.

Comment: @Greg Then please accept my answer, because then the question no longer remains in the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @KeksDose a question is only on the unanswered list if it has no *upvoted* answer

Comment: I'm recieving this error seemingly with longer conversations. Do you know how to fix this? 
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ‍ (U+200D)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.204 \end{verbatim}

Comment: Wait, this actually doesn't work, because it means that the text flows off the page for some reason?