# Tikz node and nonalphanumeric characters

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I cannibalised some code from the thread [Simple speech bubbles, arrows or balloon like shapes in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38805/2693). It works really well, but crashes whenever non-alphanumeric characters are used in the node. Here's the code

```
\newcommand{\callouts}[3]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0,outer sep=0]%
    (#3){\colorbox{#1!20}{#3}};\node[overlay,rectangle callout,%
    callout relative pointer={(0cm,0.5cm)},fill=#1!20] at ($(#3.south)+(-0cm,-0.7cm)$){#2};}%
    }%
```

And this is what it creates;

[image]

However, when I try to highlight and label a string with a non-alphanumeric character, e.g. comma or a mathematical symbol, the command crashes. I've tried using math mode and the `\text{}` command, but neither of these work. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Instead of posting a fragment of code, it's much more helpful to post a complete minimal example that shows your problem. This will make is easier for people to help you.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Meant to to that.

I'm still having difficulties with using certain maths symbols, e.g. the \neg operator. I've tried putting this in brackets, using \text, and using math mode.

Comment: @NickRiches please see my updated answer for a solution allowing the use of `\neg`; no need for extra braces now.

Comment: Cheers that's brill

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the string that is used for the label contents of the node is also used also to provide a name for the node and this can cause problems; the solution is to use another (simpler) string for naming the node; in the following example I use a counter to provide the name for the nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows}

\newcounter{mycallout}

\newcommand{\callouts}[3]{%
  \stepcounter{mycallout}
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0,outer sep=0]%
    (\themycallout) {\colorbox{#1!20}{#3}};\node[overlay,rectangle callout,%
    callout relative pointer={(0cm,0.5cm)},fill=#1!20] at ($(\themycallout.south)+(-0cm,-0.7cm)$){#2};}%
    }%

\begin{document}

\callouts{blue}{text;$a\neg$}{text,$a\neg$}

\end{document}
```

[image]