# Creating picture using LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

I want to create picture on the following link.

How can I create this picture using LaTeX? I have tried different things but nothing works.

[image]

Reference: p.510 of http://www.pearsonschoolsandfecolleges.co.uk/Secondary/Mathematics/14-16/EdexcelGCSEMathematics/Samples/StudentBooksamples/SamplepagesfromLinearHigherStudentBook.pdf

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. This is a question-answer site and not intended for "do it for me" questions. Please provide some code that others can help you improve.

Comment: I have tried different things which are mentioned on this site, but they are very different from what I want to do, therefore right now, I dont have a code.

Comment: Look at the tikz manual.  At least one diagram from your file is almost identical to one of the tutorials.

Comment: Can you give an example of the things that didn't work out for you on this site?

Comment: I have tried example with Caroot Van Gogh on the following link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38805/simple-speech-bubbles-arrows-or-balloon-like-shapes-in-beamer

Comment: I have seen in tikz manual but there is no example there which I can use, if there is one can you please give me page number thnaks.

Comment: There are over 20 pages in the linked PDF, and many times more pictures. Things preventing others from providing a useful answer include: (a) which figure on which page are you trying to do first? (b) what code can you show that accomplishes *part* of that figure? (c) what is the next missing feature you'd like to add to your partially-working code?

Comment: It is on page 510 and the figure I want to do in figure 2 on the page, that with $$T=1/2ab\Sin C = 1/2ba\Sin A=1/2ac\Sin B.$$

Comment: That takes care of part (a). Could you edit your question to provide parts (b) and (c)?

Comment: I am trying differents things, but my main problem is to write formula in one line and then make two differnt speech boxes.

Comment: writing following code \calloutquote[.4\textwidth]{Immanuel didn't really say this}{$4c+9asd+sad$} gives a box with filled color which I dont want

Comment: Note: this is *very* different from the normal use of "callouts"; in the linked image, it looks as if the formula in the first line was actually *spoken* by the formulae in the second line, which doesn't make sense.  I'd change callouts into something different, like maybe rectangles with rounded corners with arrows or plain lines attached.  This is not necessarily *easier* to do with tikz, but imho would be much better as far as *communication* with the reader goes.

Comment: I cannot understand the point with this forum, after so many hours, if I cannot make this diagram, and nobody want to help me, why we have this forum? If I was an expert in this then I was not asking questions on this forum. It is waste of time. Nothing else.

Comment: Can somebody help me to make this diagram which I am trying to make for my class. I have sent hours and hours, but with no result.

Comment: Of the three hours this question has been open, the first hour was spent in simply getting you to specify which picture you were trying to recreate. During the second hour, *I* posted a screenshot of your desired result for you, in an attempt to prompt more experienced people to work something out.

This is not a site where you can post a "tell me how to do this entire thing" without showing at least a minimal amount of effort in making a question specific enough to be answered, and/or showing what progress you've already attempted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a small code which can be used as a start.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,matrix}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,nodes={minimum width=6cm,text width=5.8cm}]
  {
    \rlap{Area of triangle $ABC=\frac12ab\sin C=\frac12bc\sin A=\frac12ca\sin B$} \\[1cm]
  \everymath{\color{red}}  $\frac12ab\sin C=\frac12bc\sin A$ &
  \everymath{\color{green}}  $\frac12bc\sin A=\frac12ca\sin B$ \\
  \everymath{\color{red}} cancelling $\frac12$ and $b$ from both sides &   
  \everymath{\color{green}} cancelling $\frac12$ and $c$ from both sides  \\
  };
\node[ellipse callout, draw=red, callout relative pointer={(-0.4,-0.4)},minimum width=4.6cm,minimum height=2cm] at ($(m-1-1)+(1.9,0)$) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user26421: It's only a start which can be improved.

Comment: Yes I know, and I have completed it. Thanks once again.