# Talking Balloon in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows}
 \newcommand{\bubblethis}[2]{
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0,outer sep=0]%
    (#1) {\underline{#1}};\node[overlay,cloud callout,callout relative pointer={(0.2cm,-0.7cm)},%
    aspect=2.5,fill=yellow!90] at ($(#1.north)+(-0.5cm,1.6cm)$) {#2};}%
}%

 \begin{document}
 \bubblethis{B}{I know X}
 \end{document}
```

This creates a talking bubble but I want to create bubble over bubbles. I tried using `\bubblethis` function twice but it makes second balloon twice. To see what I mean by typing `\bubblethis{B}{\bubblethis{I know X}{I know a}}`. If someone makes a good tweak the code that would be great. Thanks for any help

This picture is sort of what I want.

[image]

Comment: It is not exactly clear how you want the result to look.  Two bubbles side by side?  One small bubble sitting inside the other larger bubble?  Based on your proposed syntax, I am thinking the latter, but a clarification would help.

Comment: Is this closer to what you want??: `\setbox0=\hbox{\bubblethis{B}{I know X}}\bubblethis{A}{\box0{I know a}}`  or else `\bubblethis{B}{\bubblethis{A}{I know B}I know X}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: The first one is want I wanted except positioning, but I will figure out that. Thanks very much!

Comment: @user64066, why don't you upload an image of what you are trying to achieve so that the others would know what do you exactly mean *bubble over bubble*? Even a hand-drawn image would suffice.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38805/simple-speech-bubbles-arrows-or-balloon-like-shapes-in-beamer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am putting my answer for someone who is struggling with same type of question in order to save his/her time.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows}
 \newcommand{\bubblethis}[2]{
\tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0,outer sep=0]%
(#1) {#1};\node[overlay,cloud callout,callout relative pointer={(-0.2cm,-0.2cm)},%
aspect=1.5,fill=yellow!90] at ($(#1.north)+(0.8cm,0.4cm)$) {#2};}%
}%

\newcommand{\bubble}[3]{
\tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] %
(#1)  {#1};\node[overlay,cloud callout,callout relative pointer= {(0.2cm,-0.4cm)},aspect=2.5,fill=red] at($(#1.north)+(-0.5cm,1.6cm)$) {#2};\node[overlay,cloud callout, callout relative pointer={((-0.4,-0.3))},aspect=3,fill=green] at($(#1.north)+(2cm,4cm)$) {#3};}


}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{4cm}
\centering
\bubble{B}{I know}{\bubblethis{A}{B}}
\end{document}
```

[image: speech bubble]