# Theory of Mind Type Figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw [this picture](http://kejda.net/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/problem-of-other-minds.jpg).

[image]

I have produced multiple balloons etc., but it would be nice to produce exactly same figure. In case my primitive code may help someone, I am also adding it below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows}

\newcommand{\bubblethis}[2]{
\tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0,outer sep=0]%
(#1) {#1};\node[overlay,cloud callout,callout relative pointer={(-0.1cm,-0.1cm)},%
aspect=10,fill=yellow!90] at ($(#1.north)+(0.8cm,1.5cm)$) {#2};}%
}%

\newcommand{\bubblethat}[2]{
\tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0,outer sep=0]%
(#1) {#1};\node[overlay,cloud callout,callout relative pointer={(0cm,-0.5cm)},%
aspect=10,fill=yellow!90] at ($(#1.north)+(0.1cm,2.2cm)$) {#2};}%
}%

 \newcommand{\bubble}[3]{
 \tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] %
(#1)  {#1};\node[overlay,cloud callout,callout relative pointer={(0cm,-0.5cm)},aspect=8,fill=red] at($(#1.north)+(0.1cm,2.2cm)$) {#2};\node[overlay,cloud callout, callout relative pointer={((-0.4,-0.3))},aspect=2.5,fill=green] at($(#1.north)+(2cm,5cm)$) {#3};}
} %

\newcommand{\bubblesmall}[3]{
\tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] %
(#1)  {#1};\node[overlay,cloud callout,callout relative pointer={(0cm,-0.5cm)},aspect=8,fill=red] at($(#1.north)+(0.1cm,2.2cm)$) {#2};\node[overlay,cloud callout, callout relative pointer={((-0.4,-0.3))},aspect=2.5,fill=green] at($(#1.north)+(2cm,4cm)$) {#3};}
} %
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A related question by the same user: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183348/talking-balloon-in-tikz

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Possibly one of those occasions where nesting the `tikzpicture` environment (which is usually inadvisable) can be quite useful.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts,decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{people/.cd,
  name/.store in=\personname,
  name=,
%
% Face
%
  face size/.store in=\facesize,
  face size=1cm,
    face/.style={fill=face color, draw=none},
  face color/.code=\colorlet{face color}{#1}, face color=black!50,
  face code/.initial={
    \path [people/face/.try]
    ( 0, 6) .. controls ( 3, 6) and ( 5, 4) .. 
    ( 5, 2) .. controls ( 7, 3) and ( 6,-2) ..
    ( 5,-1) .. controls ( 5,-4) and ( 2,-7) ..
    ( 0,-7) .. controls (-2,-7) and (-5,-4) .. 
    (-5,-1) .. controls (-6,-2) and (-7, 3) ..
    (-5, 2) .. controls (-5, 4) and (-3, 6) ..
    ( 0, 6) -- cycle;
  },
/tikz/people/.cd,
  hair/.style={fill=hair color, draw=none},
  hair back code/.initial=,
  hair front code/.initial=,
  hair color/.code=\colorlet{hair color}{#1}, hair color=black,
  hair style/.is choice,
  hair style/.cd,
    shoulder length/.style={
      hair back code={
        \path [people/hair/.try]
        ( 5,-1) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=7]
        (-5,-1) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=7];
      },
      hair front code={
        \path [people/hair/.try] 
        (3,4) ellipse [x radius=3, y radius=2] 
        (2,4) ellipse [x radius=4, y radius=2];
        \path [people/hair/.try] 
        ( 3,4) ellipse [x radius=3, y radius=2] 
        (-4,4) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=2];
        \path [people/hair/.try]
        (6,4) arc (0:180:6 and 4) -- cycle;
      }
    },
    ceasar/.style={
      hair back code={
        \path [people/hair/.try]
        (-4,3) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=3]
        ( 4,3) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=3];
      },
      hair front code={
        \path [people/hair/.try]
        (5,4) arc (0:180:5 and 3);
        \path [people/hair/.try]
        ( 0,3) -- (-1,4) -- (-2,3) -- (-3,4) -- (-4,2) -- (-5,4) -- (-4,5) --
        ( 4,5) -- ( 5,4) -- ( 4,2) -- ( 3,4) -- ( 2,3) -- ( 1,4) -- cycle;
      }
    },
}

\tikzset{%
  pics/person/.style={%
    code={
      \tikzset{people/.cd,#1, /tikz/.cd,scale=\facesize/13cm}%
      \begin{scope}[local bounding box/.expanded=\personname]
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/people/hair back code}
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/people/face code}
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/people/hair front code}
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/people/facial hair code}
      \end{scope}
    } 
  },
  think bubble/.style={
    align=center,
    ellipse callout,
    minimum width=1cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm, 
    anchor=pointer,
    decoration={random steps, segment length=5pt, amplitude=1pt}, decorate
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic {person={hair style/ceasar, name=jack}};
\node [think bubble, fill=gray!50] at (jack.north) {$z$};


\pic at (2.5,0) {person={hair style/shoulder length, name=jill}};
\node [think bubble, fill=gray!25] at (jill.north) {%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75, transform shape]
   \pic {person={hair style/ceasar, name=jack}};
   \node [think bubble, fill=gray!50] at (jack.north) {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}\\$y$};


\pic at (6,0) {person={hair style/ceasar, name=jack}};
\node [think bubble, fill=gray!50] at (jack.north) {%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75, transform shape]
  \pic {person={hair style/shoulder length, name=jill}};
  \node [think bubble, fill=gray!25]at (jill.north) {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape]
     \pic {person={hair style/ceasar, name=jack}};
     \node [think bubble, fill=gray!50] at (jack.north) {$z$};
  \end{tikzpicture}\\$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}\\$x$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if more hairstyles are required then one can simply take from these:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  face size/.store in=\facesize, 
  face size=1cm,
    face/.style={fill=face color, draw=none},
  face color/.code=\colorlet{face color}{#1}, face color=black!50,
  face code/.initial={
    \path [face/.try]
    ( 0, 6) .. controls ( 3, 6) and ( 5, 4) .. 
    ( 5, 2) .. controls ( 7, 3) and ( 6,-2) ..
    ( 5,-1) .. controls ( 5,-4) and ( 2,-7) ..
    ( 0,-7) .. controls (-2,-7) and (-5,-4) .. 
    (-5,-1) .. controls (-6,-2) and (-7, 3) ..
    (-5, 2) .. controls (-5, 4) and (-3, 6) ..
    ( 0, 6) -- cycle;
  }
}

\tikzset{ 
    facial hair/.style={fill=hair color, draw=none},
    facial hair code/.initial=,
  facial hair/.cd,
    clean shaven/.style={
        facial hair code=,
    },
    moustache/.style={
        facial hair code={
            \path [facial hair/.try]
            (0,-1) 
            .. controls ( 1, 0) and ( 2,-2) .. ( 2,-3)
            .. controls ( 1,-3) and ( 1,-2) .. ( 0,-2)
            .. controls (-1,-2) and (-1,-3) .. (-2,-3)
            .. controls (-2,-2) and (-1, 0) .. (0, -1)
            -- cycle;
        }
    },
    goatee/.style={
        facial hair code={
            \path [facial hair/.try]
            (0,-5) circle [radius=3];
            \path [face/.try]
            (0,-4) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=1];
        }
    },
    beard/.style={
        facial hair code={
                \path [facial hair/.try]
                [shift=({-3,-4.5}), rotate=30]  ellipse [x radius=1.5, y radius=3.5];
                \path [facial hair/.try]
                [shift=({ 3,-4.5}), rotate=-30] ellipse [x radius=1.5, y radius=3.5];
                \path [facial hair/.try]
                (0,-5) ellipse [x radius=4, y radius=3];
                \path [face/.try]
                (0,-4) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=1];
            }
    },
    stubble/.style={
        facial hair code={
            \path [facial hair/.try, fill=hair color!50!face color]
            ( 0,-2) 
            .. controls ( 2,-2) and ( 3,-4) .. ( 5,-1) 
            .. controls ( 5,-4) and ( 2,-7) .. ( 0,-7)
            .. controls (-2,-7) and (-5,-4) .. (-5,-1)
            .. controls (-3,-4) and (-2,-2) .. ( 0,-2)
            -- cycle;
            \path [face/.try]
            (0,-4) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=1];
        }
    }
}
\tikzset{
  hair/.style={fill=hair color, draw=none},
  hair back code/.initial=,
  hair front code/.initial=,
  hair color/.code=\colorlet{hair color}{#1}, hair color=black,
  hair style/.is choice,
  hair style/.cd,
    none/.style={
      hair back code=,
      hair front code=,
    },
    bald/.style={
      hair back code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        (4, 2) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=3]
        (-4,2) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=3];
      },
      hair front code=,
    },
    curly/.style={
      hair back code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        (5, -5) circle [radius=2] (-5,-5) circle [radius=2]
        (6, -2) circle [radius=2] (-6,-2) circle [radius=2]
        (-6, 1) circle [radius=2] (6, 1)  circle [radius=2];
      },
      hair front code={
        \path [hair/.try] 
        (5,4) circle [radius=2] 
        (3,6) circle [radius=2]
        (-5,4) circle [radius=2] 
        (-3,6) circle [radius=2]
        (0,6) circle [radius=2];
      }
    },
    punk/.style={
      hair back code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        (-1, 5) -- ( 0, 8) -- ( 1, 5) -- cycle
        (-4, 3) -- (-6, 6) -- (-3, 4) -- cycle
        ( 4, 3) -- ( 6, 6) -- ( 3, 4) -- cycle
        (-3, 5) -- (-3, 7) -- (-1, 5) -- cycle
        ( 3, 5) -- ( 3, 7) -- ( 1, 5) -- cycle;
      },
      hair front code={
        \path [hair/.try] 
        (-3, 3) -- (-4, 5) -- (-2, 4) -- cycle
        ( 3, 3) -- ( 4, 5) -- ( 2, 4) -- cycle
        (-1, 4) -- ( 0, 6) -- ( 1, 4) -- cycle
        (-1, 2) -- ( 0, 3) -- ( 1, 2) -- cycle;
      }
    },
    bob/.style={
      hair back code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        ( 5,0) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=6]
        (-5,0) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=6];
        \path [hair/.try]
        (-5,-6) rectangle (5, -2);
      },
      hair front code={
        \path [hair/.try] 
        ( 3,4) ellipse [x radius=3, y radius=2] 
        (-3,4) ellipse [x radius=3, y radius=2];
        \path [hair/.try]
        (6, 4) arc (0:180:6 and 4) -- cycle;
      }
    },
    shoulder length/.style={
      hair back code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        ( 5,-1) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=7]
        (-5,-1) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=7];
      },
      hair front code={
        \path [hair/.try] 
        (3,4) ellipse [x radius=3, y radius=2] 
        (2,4) ellipse [x radius=4, y radius=2];
        \path [hair/.try] 
        ( 3,4) ellipse [x radius=3, y radius=2] 
        (-4,4) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=2];
        \path [hair/.try]
        (6,4) arc (0:180:6 and 4) -- cycle;
      }
    },
    neutral/.style={
      hair back code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        ( 4,1) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=4]
        (-4,1) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=4];
      },
      hair front code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        (-5,2) ellipse [x radius=1, y radius=2]
        ( 5,2) ellipse [x radius=1, y radius=2];
        \path [hair/.try]
        (-6,2) 
        .. controls (-6,5) and (-3,7) .. ( 0,7) 
        .. controls ( 3,7) and ( 6,5) .. ( 6,2)
        .. controls ( 4,2) and ( 3,2) .. ( 2,4)
        .. controls ( 1,2) and (-3,0) .. (-6,2) -- cycle;
      }
    },
    afro 70s/.style={
      hair back code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        (0,2) ellipse [x radius=7, y radius=6];
      },
      hair front code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        ( 0,7)
        .. controls ( 3,7) and ( 6,2) .. ( 5,3)
        .. controls ( 2,6) and (-3,1) .. (-5,4)
        .. controls (-6,6) and (-3,7) .. ( 0,7)
        -- cycle;
        \path [hair/.try]
        (-4, 5) 
        .. controls (-4, 3) and (-5, 0) .. (-4,-2)
        .. controls (-3,-4) and (-3,-5) .. (-4,-4)
        .. controls (-5,-3) and (-7, -1) .. (-6, 3)
        .. controls (-6, 5) and (-5, 5) .. (-4, 5)
        -- cycle;
        \path [hair/.try, xscale=-1]
        (-4, 5) 
        .. controls (-4, 3) and (-5, 0) .. (-4,-2)
        .. controls (-3,-4) and (-3,-5) .. (-4,-4)
        .. controls (-5,-3) and (-7, -1) .. (-6, 3)
        .. controls (-6, 5) and (-5, 5) .. (-4, 5)
        -- cycle;       
      }
    },
    scruffy/.style={
      hair back code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        (-6,1) -- (-7,2) -- (-6,3) -- (-7,4) -- (-6,5) -- (-6,6) -- 
        (-5,6) -- (-4,7) -- (-3,7) -- (-2,8) -- (-1,7) -- ( 0,8) --
        ( 1,7) -- ( 2,8) -- ( 3,7) -- ( 4,7) -- ( 5,6) -- ( 6,6) --
        ( 6,5) -- ( 7,4) -- ( 6,3) -- ( 7,2) -- ( 6,1) -- cycle; 
      },
      hair front code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        (0,2) -- (-1,3) -- (-2,2) -- (-3,2) -- (-4,1) -- (-5,2) -- (-5,4) --
        (-1,7) -- (1,7) --
        (5,4) -- (5,2) -- (4,1) -- (3,2) -- (2,2) -- (1,3) -- cycle;
      }
    },
    pig-tails/.style={
      hair back code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        (-4,1) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=4]
        ( 4,1) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=4];
      },
      hair front code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        ( 0,3) .. controls (-3,1) and (-4,2) ..
        (-5,1) .. controls (-6,5) and (-3,6) ..
        ( 0,6) .. controls ( 3,6) and ( 6,5) ..
        ( 5,1) .. controls ( 4,2) and ( 3,1) ..
        ( 0,3) -- cycle;
        \path [hair/.try]
        (-4,3) -- (-8,6) -- (-7,6) -- (-8,8) -- 
        (-6,7) -- (-6,8) -- (-3,4) -- cycle
        ( 4,3) -- ( 8,6) -- ( 7,6) -- ( 8,8) -- 
        ( 6,7) -- ( 6,8) -- ( 3,4) -- cycle;
      }
    },
    ceasar/.style={
      hair back code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        (-4,3) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=3]
        ( 4,3) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=3];
      },
      hair front code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        (5,4) arc (0:180:5 and 3);
        \path [hair/.try]
        ( 0,3) -- (-1,4) -- (-2,3) -- (-3,4) -- (-4,2) -- (-5,4) -- (-4,5) --
        ( 4,5) -- ( 5,4) -- ( 4,2) -- ( 3,4) -- ( 2,3) -- ( 1,4) -- cycle;
      }
    },
    male short/.style={
       hair back code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        (-4,3) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=3]
        ( 4,3) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=3];
      },
      hair front code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        ( 0,7) .. controls (-3,7) and (-5,6) .. 
        (-5,4) .. controls (-5,0) and ( 1,5) ..
        ( 5,4) .. controls ( 5,6) and ( 3,7) ..
        ( 0,7) -- cycle;
      }
    },
    side parting/.style={
      hair back code={
        \path [hair/.try]
        ( 4,1) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=4]
        (-4,1) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=4];
      },
      hair front code={
        \path [hair/.try,xscale=-1]
        (-6,2) 
        .. controls (-6,5) and (-3,7) .. ( 0,7) 
        .. controls ( 3,7) and ( 6,5) .. ( 6,2)
        .. controls ( 4,2) and ( 3,2) .. ( 2,4)
        .. controls ( 1,2) and (-3,0) .. (-6,2) -- cycle;
      }
    },
    afro/.style={
    hair back code={
            \path [hair/.try]
            (0,2) ellipse [x radius=7, y radius=6];
          },
        hair front code={
            \path [hair/.try]
            (0,7)
            .. controls ( 3,7) and ( 5,6) .. ( 5,4)
            .. controls ( 3,0) and (-3,5) .. (-5,3)
            .. controls (-5,5) and (-3,7) .. ( 0,7)
            -- cycle;
        },
    }
}

\tikzset{%
  pics/person/.style={%
    code={
      \tikzset{#1, scale=\facesize/13cm}%
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hair back code}
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/face code}
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hair front code}
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/hair front code}
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/facial hair code}
    } 
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \hairstyle [count=\i from 0] in {none,bald,curly,punk,bob,shoulder length,%
neutral,afro,scruffy,pig-tails,ceasar,male short,side parting,afro 70s}{
  \path ({mod(\i,4)*2}, {-floor(\i/4)*2}) 
    node [below=0.5cm, font=\small, text height=1em] {\hairstyle} 
    pic {person={hair style/\hairstyle}};
}

\foreach \facialhair [count=\i from 16]in {clean shaven,moustache,beard,goatee,stubble}{

  \path  ({mod(\i,4)*2}, {-floor(\i/4)*2})
     node [below=0.5cm, font=\small, text height=1em] {\facialhair} 
     pic {person={facial hair/\facialhair}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are an artist.

Comment: Did you find the paths for the hairstyles using trial and error, or with a drawing program?

Comment: `none == clean shaven`

Comment: @cyanide-basedfood (or whatever name this changes to in the future) the facial hair examples are all with a "default" head. The `clean shaven` option would "cancel out" any of the other facial hair options but the `none` hair style would not. Besides in my experience facial hair is independent of the hair on the top of the head; perhaps your experience is different.

Comment: Confirmed. Thanks. This comment will be removed shortly.

Comment: @Jake for most of these I used [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org) with the "snap to grid" option (as I prefer integer coordinates). Some of the hair styles were either simple tweaks of existing hair styles or just very simple and could be done by trial and error.

Comment: @MarkWibrow: Using the snap to grid option is a really good idea! Thanks

Comment: Package them for CTAN :-)!

Comment: If I could upvote twice, I would. Could you possibly tell me what `some new key/.cd` does? I've been confused by this before and I see that you use it a number of times here. By the way, you seem to set `/tikz/hair front code` twice.

Comment: @cfr the `.cd` "handler" makes `some new key` the parent path. So `\pgfkeys{some new key/.cd, key1=a, key2=b}` is implicitly prefixing `key1` and `key2` with `some new key` (i.e., `some new key/key1=a, some new key/key2=b`). It is (I believe)  analogous to the `cd` command for changing directories in a terminal. And yes that was a unnecessary duplication of `hair front code`, I've updated the code.

Comment: Thanks very much. That's very helpful. I kept expecting it to have something to do with *code* and couldn't make any sense of it at all.

Comment: I turned this inot a Ti*k*Z library for my own use, but it would be great to see this on CTAN.

Comment: Please consider to publish your work to CTAN as a Ti*k*Z-library or a package, compare http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpeople.

Comment: Support @CampanIgnis ' idead. This should be in CTAN.

Comment: @MarkWibrow What about longer hair (say, the classic length)?