# TikZ silhouette of human face seen from the side

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am trying to make this picture in TikZ.[image: camera lens angles]

I wondered if anyone had already needed a silhouette of a human face, and therefore maybe had some code for a plot or something.

Just in case anyone had something :)

Comment: Why do you want to make it in Ti*k*Z particularly?

Comment: I think you're better off with some other tools to create this image; perhaps the right part could be done in TikZ but then you have to assemble it with the left part so I would feel that TikZ is not necessarily the right tool for it

Comment: Just because these are roughly related and someone might need them: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198378/theory-of-mind-type-figure/198500#198500 and http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpeople.

Comment: @cfr Why would I not want to make it in Tikz ;) 
#TikzIsLoveTikzIsLife

Comment: @mriisa Better things to do than reproduce copies of pictures you already have? Ti*k*Z is one tool.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Based on [Mark Wibrow's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370968/75284), but I took your image and [traced it](https://inkscape.org/doc/tutorials/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html) in Inkscape, then used the coordinates from the SVG file (opening it in a text editor and finding the list of coordinates of the only path in the file).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt,scale=0.5]
\fill svg {m 182.9096,88.444477 c -2.34429,1.69819 -10.69606,9.25471 -18.55947,16.792243 -7.86342,7.53754 -16.72662,15.1454 -19.69601,16.90634 -7.33508,4.34996 -14.02508,6.06658 -17.91723,4.59746 -2.00784,-0.75788 -2.98165,-0.78599 -2.98165,-0.0861 0,0.57166 2.33047,5.34959 5.17882,10.61764 2.84835,5.26804 5.75892,12.07374 6.46793,15.12377 1.28283,5.51846 1.27227,5.57377 -2.16451,11.34315 -4.64576,7.79891 -7.006,16.47149 -9.04463,33.23394 -1.61026,13.24024 -1.60989,14.3682 0.007,20 2.48668,8.66344 5.58653,13.38376 13.7567,20.94808 11.40993,10.56384 21.06008,14.49507 35.73057,14.55575 5.40602,0.0224 9.49121,0.55022 11.0685,1.43021 1.75239,0.97768 4.33986,1.22561 8.65248,0.82907 4.58387,-0.42148 7.45696,-0.0966 11.26901,1.27416 4.84354,1.74171 5.27047,1.74894 8.00181,0.1355 1.58691,-0.93741 4.16585,-1.71257 5.73099,-1.72258 3.48723,-0.0223 9.95739,-4.30336 17.60297,-11.6472 l 5.76308,-5.53566 -2.04932,-2.64947 c -1.12713,-1.4572 -3.13387,-4.22446 -4.45942,-6.14946 l -2.4101,-3.5 1.85934,-10.5 c 1.02264,-5.775 2.52292,-12.61144 3.33396,-15.1921 1.29344,-4.11561 1.29523,-4.9482 0.0146,-6.77656 -1.36003,-1.94171 -0.97548,-2.76311 5.6153,-11.99444 9.14064,-12.80275 9.17529,-14.61145 0.32531,-16.97766 -4.03704,-1.07938 -4.24923,-1.3223 -4.23469,-4.84777 0.008,-2.0413 0.43566,-4.37618 0.94941,-5.18862 0.63908,-1.01062 0.42737,-2.03709 -0.6703,-3.25 -1.47463,-1.62945 -1.46541,-1.92642 0.11404,-3.67169 1.6304,-1.80157 1.61488,-1.9714 -0.30292,-3.31467 -1.91958,-1.34453 -1.94795,-1.65973 -0.56345,-6.26008 2.05729,-6.83587 1.88174,-7.9346 -1.91017,-11.9552 -3.18261,-3.37455 -3.7217,-3.5712 -9.7899,-3.5712 -3.532,0 -9.10387,0.72919 -12.38192,1.62043 -10.41466,2.83154 -9.82692,2.90075 -12.88895,-1.51776 -1.74758,-2.52176 -3.00238,-5.86359 -3.31549,-8.82999 -0.27709,-2.62497 -1.29173,-5.67268 -2.25476,-6.77268 -3.06651,-3.50263 -4.17031,-6.546563 -4.84401,-13.358233 -0.5603,-5.66516 -0.95709,-6.68474 -2.69853,-6.93402 -1.1229,-0.16073 -3.9597,1.09719 -6.30399,2.79539 z};

\draw[dashed] (8.5,6.6) --++ (1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

By the way, in the image you want to recreate, the camera viewfinder seems to be positioned too high (pointing to his eyebrows). I fixed it in my example.

Comment: Nice, mind writing a few words on how one traces in Inkscape? For us Inkscape novices?

Comment: @daleif: I added a link to a guide.

Comment: If you want you could use this to optimize the decimals: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

Comment: Related question with a few ways to trace an image and convert it to tikz https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340930/advices-on-drawing-a-complex-figure-using-tikz

Answer (score 12):

Not quite as detailed as the required picture but created using Inkscape and copying the path from the xml editor into a TikZ path using the `svg.path` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\begin{document}
\tikz\fill svg {M 29,64 
  C 23,64 17,63 13,61 C  9,59  4,52  2,47 C  0,42  3,28  8,22 
  C 13,16 10,14  8, 8 C 10, 5 26, 6 29, 0 C 30, 2 34, 5 36, 6 
  C 38, 7 41, 8 43, 7 C 45, 6 50, 5 52, 7 C 54, 9 53,11 53,12 
  C 53,13 55,16 55,17 C 55,18 53,19 53,20 C 53,21 56,22 56,23 
  C 56,24 54,25 54,28 C 54,31 62,31 62,33 C 62,35 54,41 53,43 
  C 52,45 50,51 49,54 C 48,57 53,60 51,61 C 49,62 35,64 29,64 Z};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A search on openclipart.org for `silhouette head` provides a rich  source of more detailed profiles (along with some less detailed ones and some not-really-silhouette ones).

Comment: Could you say what you mean by 'the xml editor'? Is this part of Inkscape? I've exported to Ti*k*Z code from there, but the result is usually much, much, much less elegant than your path. (But that could be for other reasons.)

Comment: @cfr isn't it just from the normal svg file for the drawing? Thanks s just XML data and the data Mark is using is presumably listed verbatim in the svg file. That what I've used the times where I've copied svg data to tikz.

Comment: @daleif So you mean that 'the xml editor' could just be `vim`?

Comment: @cfr yep, some people use dedicated editors others go native.

Comment: @daleif Thanks. I didn't realise that SVG was just XML, so I thought I must need some special editing thing to access the XML in the SVG, if you see what I mean. Now it makes more sense :-).

Comment: @cfr try looking inside a svg. I have no idea what the things does, but it works. My university has a truetype font with four logos in it. For some reason we cannot get pdflatex to access those slots. So I converted the font to svg via fontforge (it has a powerful cli scripting lang) and just used the svg data in tikz. Looks really nice and fast as well.

Comment: @daleif You need to reencode the font. Thanks.

Comment: @cfr even xelatex or lualatex could not access the correct slots (one if them could, not the other). It was too much work trying to get it to work, would also make it harder for users to install the stuff where we needed the logos.

Comment: @daleif For logos, your solution seems better anyway. But I'd be surprised in pdfTeX couldn't access the slots, with appropriate support files. Unless the font is just downright seriously buggy. The fact that Xe/LuaTeX can't access it doesn't mean much. I'm not talking about pdfTeX accessing it directly. You are not reencoding for the modern engines, so it is a different kind of thing. But there's no much point for four glyphs.

Comment: @cfr `ctrl-shift-X` in Inkscape produces the XML editor

Answer (score 4):

with a free image from https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/13/18/23/man-33153_960_720.png

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{/tmp/man}
\reflectbox{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{/tmp/man}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not directly from the side, but the `marvosym` package also contains a human face:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[scale=10] {\MartinVogel};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And not directly a human, but seen from the side:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{simpsons}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {\Burns};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the `pgfornament` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=10mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfornament}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfornament{164}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]